# unscheduling a scheduled task in Android with ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I use a scheduler to ensure that my loop does not take too long, so I exit the loop if the scheduler fires and ends the loop.

This is quite straight forward:

```
public void startSchedulerForTimeout() {

    Log.i("x", "SCHEDULING TIMEOUT " );
    timeoutForLoopReached = false;
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timeoutForLoopReached = true;
        Log.i("x", "SET TIMEOUT FLAG ");
        }
     }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

so in my code I just write:

```
startSchedulerForUSBMessageTimeout();
while (!done && !timeoutForLoopReached) {
  ...do the loop stuff
}
```

To make sure that the scheduled task does not fire when I run the loop again I need to unschedule the obsolete task (in case I ended the loop before timeout) so that the new timer will start again at the beginning of a new loop (instead of the old one firing after the first loop has been finished right in between the second time the loop executes)

How can I just unschedule any scheduled task that has not been fired to avoid this scheduled task mixup?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ScheduledFuture](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable longRunningTask = new Runnable();

// schedule long running task in 2 minutes:
ScheduledFuture scheduleFuture = scheduledTaskExecutor.schedule(longRunningTask, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

... ...
// At some point in the future, if you want to cancel scheduled task:
scheduleFuture.cancel(true);
... ...
```

Comment: super - thanks very much. By the way if all this is in one method and the complete method exits after 1 minute. Will the schedule task still exist or does it get killed automatically since the methods has finished? Also, if I cancel the same scheduleFuture more than once will this cause problems? or do I need to keep track if it is canceled (or executed) already?

Comment: By the way, I just exited the app and the debugger keeps on printing - and it does not look like backlogs of debugger output. So the app keeps on running even though I pressed "back" until the app exits? strange, isn't it?

Comment: @user387184 1. Scheduled task will not get killed automatically. using ScheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow() to kill all running and waiting tasks. 2. check out the cancel() method API: _Attempts  3. to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason._ 3. check out the API, there are many other useful API from ScheduledFuture class, getDelay(), isCancelled(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

All overrides of [`schedule`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) return a `ScheduledFuture` which is a `Future` which has a [`cancel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method.